# Change in privileges after recalculation of reputation?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign, reputation, users

Will there be any change in privileges (vote up, flag offensive, etc.) for users after recalculation of reputation?

Still last week in Stack Overflow, my reputation was around 525 and I got my Organizer badge (first retag) and after the change in the way reputation calculated I have got a reputation around 395. I still have the Organizer tag but no privilege to retag any question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was raised in the short period we had between hearing about the plan and its implementation. There were no signs that the team felt it was necessary.

You earned the badge, so you get to keep it. You'll get the privilege back soon enough, I imagine.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to get the rep back to the level required for the privileges.

Answer (score 0):

The only badge that's ever been taken away from what I know is the Beta badge on SO. Apart from that, if you've earned a badge, it's yours to keep. The privileges, however, can be won and lost depending on your rep.