# Does loss of reputation cause loss of privileges?

Tags: support, reputation, privileges

Do you lose privileges if you lose reputation (e.g. by spending it on bounties) and dip below what you had to reach to gain that privilege? Or, do you get to keep a privilege once it is earned no matter what?

Comment: +1 though I can't believe this question wasn't asked before!

Comment: @Trufa Challenge accepted, [previous asking found](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67847/can-you-lose-an-ability-if-your-reputation-falls-below-a-threshold "Can you lose an ability if your reputation falls below a threshold?"). Now, not duplicates, but [here are](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4780/lose-rep-accomplishments) [some related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43361/change-in-privileges-after-recalculation-of-reputation) [questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11930/notify-user-when-setting-a-bounty-will-revoke-a-privilege).

Comment: @Grace, was that link there??? I swear I need a good night sleep :) Sorry! Deleted the comment to avoid confusion. Thanks again!

Comment: @Trufa actually it was, only 'abilities' term is used instead of 'privileges'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You must maintain a privilege's rep requirements to maintain that privilege.

Badges work a little differently.  You always get to keep a badge, once earned.  However, if you lose the requirements for that badge, your next badge earned in that badge category is a "makeup" one.

Comment: Except for tag badges, which are revoked if you fail to maintain your tag score.

Comment: @Grace What?!?!  That means I could lose my subjective tag badge as questions are migrated or deleted!  OH NOES!  The horror!

Comment: How come one loose req for a badge ? Recently (before 48 hours) my [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/132621/173001) got 10th vote up ( actually 12+ & 2- ) but still I didnt receive my "Nice Badge".

Comment: @AdamDavis think about tag cleanups :D

Comment: @Łukasz웃Lツ Well the bigger problem, of course, is the upcoming meta split.  It's possible I'll lose my [stackoverflow silver badge](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/56/stackoverflow)!