# Reputation on page or actual reputation for gaining privileges

Tags: discussion, reputation

On Meta I have a reputation of 1999 and would soon cross 2000 to get a privilege to "*Edit other people’s posts, vote to approve or reject suggested edits*".

However when I check my reputation on https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation page, it shows I am 20 rep short of the 2000. But would I get the required privilege based on the rep shown on the page or my actual rep as given in the https://meta.stackoverflow.com/reputation?

Comment: Related / Dupe -  [Does loss of reputation cause loss of privileges?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/does-loss-of-reputation-cause-loss-of-privileges)

Comment: @Sathya - Not really a dupe. I have gone through other question on meta, but none of them say which reputation is taken into consideration. The one on your home page or the one in your reputation page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But would I get the required privilege based on the rep shown on the page or my actual rep

It's based on your rep shown on the `/users` page. If you trigger the rep recalc, then you lose the privilege(s) till you get it back up to the required privilege level