# Where can I find how many edits I've made?

Tags: support, edits, profile-page

Is it possible to know how many edits I've made until now (on Stack Overflow for example)?
I think that would a nice feature to be posted somewhere on my profile.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's actually on the Users tab.

1. Navigate to the [Users tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users).
2. Click on the [editors subtab](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors).
3. Select the [all filter](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=all).
4. Search for your name.

[image: StackOverflow Edit]

Comment: Note that the total given here will be less than the one on your user page, but more than the one given by the "Copy Editor" badge progress. For me they show (respectively): 334, 577, and 277. This is because they are counting different types of edits. For example, "Copy Editor" doesn't count tag edits.

Answer (score 13):

Its there in your profile,

- Go to Activity Tab
- Click on Suggestions ( till < 2K Reputation )
- Click on Revisions ( after 2K Reputation )

**Suggestions Snap**

> [image]

**Revisions Snap**

> [image]

Comment: -1,  not enough FHRC....

Comment: what is the meaning of FHRC ? @Lix

Comment: Free Hand Red Circles...

Comment: which red circles ?

Comment: Exactly :P  You are missing some ;)

Comment: ok, you mean  i should circle the "Suggestion" and "Revisiont" title in the image, right ?

Comment: Just to put some emphasis on them... yes :P

Comment: ok, give me sometime, i will be back with the modifications you suggested. As you can see a Dark Background on the Suggestion and Revision Title, I thought not to change it. But i will do it now , as you suggest

Comment: ok @Lix, its done

Comment: Hehe - if I could upvote again I would :)

Comment: that's ok, but i think you can change your voting, once the edit has been done.

Comment: I did't downvote at all - it was a joke - must have been someone else...

Comment: well then ok, you can easily vote up :P

Comment: But I did that already :P

Comment: @gnat nice trick, didn't think of that! :)

Comment: yes, Impressed, he has very much experience of editing :) @ShaDowWizArd

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd "pay it forward" as they used to say here at Meta: next time you see someone's screen shot undistinguishable, edit the post with quote trick. After all I am doing forward-pay right now: someone else taught me the trick and I am returning that past favor now to you :)

Answer (score 6):

If you go to:

https://stackoverflow.com/review

it will tell you your progress towards the [Strunk & White](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/12/strunk-white) and [Copy Editor](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/223/copy-editor) badges and show you how many edits you've made:

[image]

This does disappear once you've got the badges so you'll only be able to count to 500 edits this way.

Comment: But he wants to know **how many** not necessarily how close he is to the next edits related badge...

Comment: @Lix - it tells you how many you've done. I'll add a screen shot.

Comment: I realize that it does - not sure if it is still displayed after those badges are awarded...

Comment: @Lix - it's not, but then you're probably not interested after the badges have been awarded.

Comment: Which brings us back to my first comment - there was not talk about edits towards badges - only the number of edits...

Answer (score 1):

It is in your activity Tab under revisions:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/187730/af?tab=activity&sort=revisions