# When I create a bounty and lose those reputation, do I lose the privileges that come with the reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties, privileges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does loss of reputation cause loss of privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76374/does-loss-of-reputation-cause-loss-of-privileges)

If I were to create a bounty for, say, 50 reputation, would I lose all the privileges that came with those 50 rep, and then have to earn them back? I just want to make sure I understand.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the deduction of the bounty pushes your rep under a privilege threshold, you lose the privilege(s) until your reputation rises above the threshold again. Privileges are reputation-based, it doesn't matter in which way your reputation drops below a threshold.

Comment: Thanks, that explains it